# OKHTTP with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, okhttp

I have a java 8 project and I need to create an API post call.
the project uses  gradle .
I think that OKHTTP is a good solution, However I do not know what to put in the build gradle class
In some website just need to put `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'`
in the OK Http site they said

```
compileKotlin {
  kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
  }
}
compileTestKotlin {
  kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
  }
}

compileJava {
  sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

android {
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

I do not need android, just want to post to server and get response in java application (I create method to post data). (I will use it in selenium, the project is pure java)
All the examples that I found is to version 3.x, So I would like to create dependency to version 3.
(I do not know what is the difference between ver 3 to ver 4, but want something to post json/ application and get response)

I am new with gradle, and if I need something more than just add line\lines to gradle build can someone please clarify?

Can someone please advise with step by step what is the only necessary things to put in gradle build regards

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If your project is simple Java 8 project you can skip the Kotlin and Android configuration from your example above. Just import de `okhhtp` dependency in your `build.gradle`

```
plugins{
    id "java"
}
dependencies{
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.6'
    // for v4.x :
    // implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.3.1'

}
```

and use it:

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        // use the http client....

    }
}
```

Comment: since it is a new java project, do you recomend to us okhttp4

Comment: or maybe to use 3.14.6

Comment: yes of course you should start with latest version available depending on the branch you want to use :  v3.x => 3.14.6 , v4.x => 4.3.1 .  If think you can go with 4.x without risk as it's new project (see upgrading instructions to make sure : https://square.github.io/okhttp/upgrading_to_okhttp_4/ )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59787203/can-not-uset-okhttp-after-after-adding-to-gradle    this is a new issue

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I If you'd like to use it with Gradle, here is the line: `implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.3.1'`.